# Combining multiple files in a single tar file

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have 2 flat text files and want to combine them into a single tar file.
I'm trying to do it using the below command but getting extra lines in the merged file. (Attaching screenshot also)

```
tar -cvf merge.tar file1 file2
```

[image]

Can someone suggest me any other option for doing the same.

Comment: AFAIK the only 'option for doing the same' is doing the same. However, if you mean 'achieving the same' you should explain what exactly you aim: do you need to create a *tar archive* without usung a *tar* tool program? ...or maybe you need to join/concatenate the contents of the two files into a single text file?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make a *tar* archive is using the *tar* tool program, as you did.

However, if you need just to *concatenate* two files, then just use *cat*:

```
cat file1 file2 > file12
```